# Argument OutOfRangeException C# DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, outofrangeexception

i have an argument outofrangeexception for my datagridview.

i try to fill it.
It stops when i = 1;

I dont know where is my mistake but its not the array `donnee[,]`

here's my code

```
 for(int i = 0; i < donnee.Length/4; i++){
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = donnee[i,0];
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = donnee[i,1];
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = donnee[i,2];
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = donnee[i,3];
                }//REMPLIR DATAGRIDVIEW
```

Thanks

Comment: You surely forgot to call dataGridView1.Rows.Add()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are filling it, you need to add rows as you go. I *expect* that you are currently filling the default "new data" row (as zero), but you should really be allocating your own each time, simply via `.Rows.Add()`. You could do this per-row, or via `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(donnee.Length/4);` before the loop.